# shared state for The (Swift) Composable Architecture with the new ReducerProtocol

Tags: swift-composable-architecture

The TCA guys provide a [Case Study] (https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture/blob/main/Examples/CaseStudies/SwiftUICaseStudies/01-GettingStarted-SharedState.swift) for shared state using the `ReducerProtocol`.   I read the case study and nothing sinks in.

I understand the new `ReducerProtocol`. I understand I can use an `ObservedObject` with dependency injection. But I just can't fathom how to get plain-vanilla shared state working.

Would love to see some code to help me understand the simplest possible implementation of shared state with the new ReducerProtocol . . .

Comment: what do you mean by shared state in another word, here in the example they have shared the same sate with both counter and profile !

Comment: Hi YodagamaHeshan, they have an example. But provide little context, especially as how to manage shared state with the new ReducerProtocol. It appears a new dedicated Reducer is necessary for each property of shared state, that a computed property updates the individual shared properties, and that three separate reducers are run to handle two shared properties.

Comment: The Composable Architecture guys have decided to tackle shared state head-on. The beta release is here: https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture/discussions/2857

An alternate approach is https://medium.com/@oliverfoggin/shared-data-in-a-tca-app-9b16e14b75cd